# ¿Cómo cambiar colores en la matriz visweb()?

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy intentando cambiar los colores en la matriz que muestra la función `visweb()`. Por norma muestra la matriz en una escala de grises y me gustaría cambiarlo por, por ejemplo, una escala de verde.

Es esto posible?

He visto el argumento `def.col` pero no sé si su propósito es éste.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente para esto es `def.col`. Puedes generar tu propia paleta manual de colores en formato `R` o incluso `rgb`, por ejemplo:

```
data(Safariland)
numero_colores <- length(table(Safariland))
rgb_cols <- c("#FFFFFFFF", rainbow(numero_colores - 1))

visweb(Safariland, square="defined", def.col=rgb_cols)
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este ejemplo, definimos los colores aprovechando la paleta `rainbow()` y se corresponderán a estos niveles:

```
as.vector(table(Safariland))
 [1] 204  12   3   5   6   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

El primer elemento podemos ver que es el más frecuente, por lo que lo hemos configurado en blanco: `#FFFFFFFF`. Con ese orden podemos definir los colores para cada caso.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de nuevo! Volvió a solucionarme el "problema".
Habría alguna posibilidad de hacer que la escala de colores sea más suave? Es decir...Para el valor más alto un rojo muy intenso e ir quitándole intensidad al color a medida que el valor disminuye hasta llegar al blanco. En resumen, simular una escala de grises pero con el rojo, verde, azul...el color en hexadecimal que le diga.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo encontré! En lugar de utilizar la gama de colores ```rainbow()``` se pueden utilizar otras librerias de colores. He encontrado la información aquí:
[https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/top-r-color-palettes-to-know-for-great-data-visualization/]