# ¿Como poner barra de intensidad de colores en bipartite?

Tags: r

[image: La imagen muestra el fomato de los datos]Estoy haciendo un análisis,
A los datos lo llamo (este)
El escript que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
library (bipartite)
visweb(este)
visweb(este, circles=TRUE,  boxes=FALSE,  labsize=1, circle.max=3, 
    text="no")
```

Cómo puedo al grafico que me sale cambiarle el color de los circulos y ponerle una barra de colores q demuestre la intensidad de la asociación?

Comment: Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367876/c%c3%b3mo-cambiar-colores-en-la-matriz-visweb, salvo por lo de la leyenda creo que responde tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias responde mi pregunta pero necesito por ejemplo que salga un mismo color pero q disminuya la tonalidad segun la intensidad de la interacción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando el código de [`visweb()`](https://github.com/biometry/bipartite/blob/master/bipartite/R/visweb.R), lamento decirte que no se puede. En el caso de los círculos solo puedes establecer un color único para todos ellos, mediante el parámetro `circle.col`. Sin embargo, en la visualización tipo rectangular, si es posible, veamos un ejemplo dónde definimos 25 interacciones y creamos una paleta de azul a rojo de esa misma cantidad de colores

```
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol=5)
rownames(m) <- paste("V", 1:5)
colnames(m) <- rownames(m)

numero_colores <- length(table(m))
paleta <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))(numero_colores)

visweb(m, 
       text="interaction",
       textcol = "white",
       square="defined",
       labsize=.6, 
       def.col = paleta
)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La "magia" la hace [`colorRampPalette()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dichromat/versions/1.1/topics/colorRampPalette) un función base que nos retorna una función anónima que interpola colores discretos a una paleta continua de `n` colores (en este caso, la cantidad de interacciones), en nuestro ejemplo, se interpolan los colores desde el rojo al azul, pero es posible hacerlo con múltiples colores, incluso `rgb`.